# Node.js child process socket write behaving weirdly in Chrome & FF

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, child-process

I have this really simple code that seems to give some problem. The problem is only with Chrome and Firefox (I tried Opera and command line curl request and that works fine).

If I hit the URL `http://localhost:3000/` from the browser, it shoes the current timestamp. when I press refresh once, it works as expected. But after that, it only works for alternate requests. One refresh gives the result, another goes into forever waiting and eventual timeout. I faced this problem only in Chrome and Firefox. Could anyone point out why this happens?

It works fine if I remove the child process stuff, i.e. serve requests from master itself, it works perfect. I want to know, what difference does it make if I make another response object for the same socket and send data over that socket. And most importantly, what problem Chrome and FF has with this code, and why?

Server code,

```
var http = require('http');
var child_process = require('child_process');

var worker = child_process.fork('./worker.js');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url == '/favicon.ico') {
        res.end();
        return;
    }

    worker.send({ 'event': 'start' }, res.socket);
}).listen(3000);
```

And, Worker code is,

```
var http = require('http');

process.on('message', function (data, socket) {
    var response = new http.ServerResponse({});
    response.assignSocket(socket);

    response.end(new Date().getTime() + '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that Chrome must not be closing the connection of previous request. You can fix it by adding a connection `close` header in the child worker

```
var response = new http.ServerResponse({});
response.writeHead(200, {'connection': 'close'});
response.assignSocket(socket);

response.end(new Date().getTime() + '');
```

Alternatively, adding this instead of the `writeHead` will also work

```
response.shouldKeepAlive = false;
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Just tested, this fixes it in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting an issue with the socket already being claimed by the automatically generated req/res object from createServer.

Try passing the response, rather than just the socket to the child process?

Or set things up so that the child process asynchronously sends back the data only and then the main process sends the response?

Comment: Node.js doesn't allow sending the handle of all the objects. And response object is an instance of ServerResponse Class, passing which causes an error.

Comment: Also, If possible, I don't want the master to serve for the request. There will be several workers and lots of requests. I don't want all the workers to send the data using process.send. And by doing that, master will have to preserve response objects somewhere and maintain a request hash kinda thing to know which request this response belongs to. Please suggest.

Comment: That's really weird, I just tested it out a little bit and the most definitive thing I can say is that the server is not emitting a 'request' event (which is what you're listening for by passing a function to createServer).  Maybe Firefox isn't sending the request for some reason? I dunno, sorry.

Comment: Good to know that atleast the issue is consistent. Anyways. Thanks for trying.  :)

Comment: @Russbear Just FYI, you could try the fix I suggested... :)